How will the country of Lebanon be acquired today as part of the Promised Land?
Not sure exactly how to word the question but as I’m listening to the Bible, I keep hearing on the audio Bible how the Promised Land includes-wrong wording EXTENDS into Lebanon. Being that it’s its own country today (8/28/24) how will it be acquired?
Joshua 1:4 (NIV):

Your territory will extend from the desert to Lebanon, and from the great river, the Euphrates — all the Hittite country — to the Mediterranean Sea in the west.

Deuteronomy 11:24 (NIV):

Every place where you set your foot will be yours: Your territory will extend from the desert to Lebanon, and from the Euphrates River to the Mediterranean Sea.


Lyd, on Hermeneutics, showing the research upon which the Q is based is important, and you have, indeed, provided two scripture texts. What remains unexplained, however, is why you include the word "today" in the Q. If this is based upon a particular, modern interpretation of events linking end-time prophecies with the secular state of Israel, that will invite speculative answers. Is not the only biblically hermeneutic answer, The Bible does not say how, nor specify exactly when? I won't edit out the word 'today' in your Q, just leaving this thought with you. I have not voted to close your Q.

You can vote to close it- not important. I just asked a question, if it can be answered great. If not, there’s nothing I can do about it. Since you need an explanation of the word today it means 8/28/2024. I added it because yes that’s obviously how my mind processes it, now if it being a country doesn’t apply, then all you have to do is answer and say that. Simple. Thanks!

Biblical Hermeneutics is a question and answer site for understanding Biblical text (exegesis) using rules of interpretation (hermeneutics). We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist, and other viewpoints, as long as they take seriously the process of understanding Biblical texts. Answers are welcome to be diverse and must always explain the hermeneutical process, quoting Biblical texts and citing sources for facts. Please read about what we look for in answers and our flowchart for asking questions.

Not Jewish nor Atheist. But a follower of Jesus Christ-nothing that you said shows/explains that I did anything wrong. If you don’t like my serious question than no need for snarky comments. This isn’t Facebook :)

The promise made to Abraham was of the entire 'world' (to come). For the promise, that he should be the heir of the world . . . . . , Romans 4:13. It is the promised earth that shall not be formed until this one is destroyed. Any speculation about prophecy fulfillment in the present day is, inevitably, opinion-based and off-topic.

"I keep hearing how the Promised Land includes Lebanon" — you should tell us where you heard it by providing an explicit direct quotation and citation. The scriptures quoted don't indicate that it includes Lebanon.  Of course when we know what group is promoting that idea, the question becomes far more suitable for Christianity.SE than for this site.

You actually let me understand that it’s of a promised Earth that wont be formed until this one is destroyed. Thank you for that answer! Unfortunately you messed it up by saying “opinion based”??? Confusing because I come to ask questions, not state opinions. Thanks for including an actual answer!!!

If you read my question corrrectly you’d easily understand that I keep hearing it in the BIBLE as it’s being read, thus hearing. I don’t quote verses that are already in the Bible, sorry

I stated 'opinion-based' about attempts to interpret prophecies and attach them to current events. This is an hermeneutic site and such attempts would be 'off-topic'.

So then the answer would be like you said it’s a prophesy for an Earth that’s not yet formed. I would first have to know that instead of blatantly and purposefully actually attempt to interpret and attach things that don’t belong together. I wouldn’t know that unless I asked the question. Since I didn’t attach anything than it’s not “off-topic”. You can simply tell me it doesn’t apply to current events. Easy and genuine. Thanks.

The term "opinion based" is somewhat misleading it.  On this site it means that the question is likely to generate answers that are opinions rather than facts.

A first impression of the scripture is that the land extends to Lebanon, not into it (just as it extends "to the Mediterranean, without including it). What's needed is an explicit quotation from the people that say it includes Lebanon, and why they believe it.

Ok I worded it wrong. Get “includes” out of your vocabulary. The text says extends and God’s word is more important. Thanks

@Lyd, please don't let a few people discourage you from continuing to ask questions on the Biblical Hermeneutics forum. Obviously nearly all questions posted are "likely" to generate answers based on opinion, so my advice is to include a specific verse in your title and mention the word "hermeneutics".  For example, this title is far less likely to be closed: How do scholars use biblical hermeneutics to interpret the boundaries specified in Ezekiel 48:1-29?  See what I mean?

Good advice. Thank you, I’ll do that. I am going to continue to ask because I always have questions. Some might even be weird or seem like I am trying to say something against that specific verse but I’m not — I genuinely don’t get it and need help understanding it. But I’ve noticed I can cause some to get stuck on one word instead of seeing the bigger picture so I’ll try my best with wording and do what you said!

As an experiment, I took the area described in Ezekiel 48 for millennial Israel and, as an experiment, divided the land equally according to AREA rather than equal-width stripes of land. For this analysis, I used AutoCAD to create the equal areas.
There's a well-defined strip of land allocated to the Levites that includes Jerusalem, and there are 5 tribes south of that and 7 tribes north. I tried to locate the described southern boundaries of Israel (it doesn't include Eilat on the Gulf of Aqaba). As you can see, the four northern-most tribes include all of present-day Lebanon.
Here's how it worked out:

Correction: The hatched rectangular area labeled "Plus" is a small, additional area that would have to be added to the northern or northeastern border unless the southern border can be justifiably expanded a little. I spent a fair amount of time on an accurate southern boarder, which then serves as 5/12 of the total area of millennial Israel, not counting the strip reserved for the Levites.
How the Euphrates river figures into this I don't know. How this works out politically or militarily is also unknown, although I'd suspect that the majority of Lebanese would welcome peace and prosperity over the destruction and poverty resulting from mindless, genocidal hatred against Jews.
I'm assuming that this map is post-Armageddon according to Ezekiel 38 and 39 since Megiddo is in northern Israel, where Iran, Turkey, southern Russia, and a few other nations invade a peaceful Israel.

Wow! Love this. You really took your time and i am super grateful. Thank you!

Not sure the Lebanese will welcome peace and prosperity. We can only hope.

Screenshotting your perfect answer

@Lyd Perhaps we should note that Ezekiel has already modified the Joshua version of the promise by abandoning the Transjordan (which was the land of Reuben, Gad, and half of Manasseh). If it can be modified once, why should it not be modified today to leave out even the West Bank?

?? Not sure if this was an answer or a random comment???

@Stephen Disraeli, I found many of the geographical references for Ezekiel's northern and northwestern boundaries to be obscure and speculative. The hatched rectangular area could be added to the historical Transjordan area you mentioned. In addition, the area of the northern half of Lebanon might also instead be added to the Transjordan area. . . . again, this all depends on resolving obscure geographic locations in the North.

Maimonides wrote in Laws of Kings and Wars (Hilchot Melachim u'Milchamot) that during the era of the Messianic King, the restored King of Israel will restore the full kingdom:

בִּימֵי הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ. כְּשֶׁתִּתְיַשֵּׁב מַמְלַכְתּוֹ וְיִתְקַבְּצוּ אֵלָיו כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל.

Precisely how the Messiah will accomplish this is not stated in any sources. Maimonides further states that the Messianic age will not cause an end to the natural order:

Do not presume that in the Messianic age any facet of the world's nature will change or there will be innovations in the work of creation. Kings and Wars Ch 12

So it's entirely possible the Messiah will conquer these lands militarily in order to restore Israel fully.

Really confused with the whole don’t presume thing. That’s why I asked a question for a knowledgeable answer but it seems I shouldn’t have asked it. Thank you for atleast providing a partial answer!
